# What is the actual/true meaning of "humanism"?

Tags: meaning

Today in school I was told "humanism" had to do with your religious ideas but in a dictionary it says,

> any system or mode of thought or action in which human interests, values, and dignity predominate.

So what does it really mean?

(I found the definition on http://www.dictionary.com/browse/humanism?s=t)

Comment: Are you in a public school, or a church school?

Comment: I go to a public school.

Comment: Many religious groups point to "humanism" as a kind of anti-religion. That may be why they said it had to do with religious ideas. Some humanists even see themselves as opponets of religion.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: When looking for information on this topic, be careful of people writing about it who have their own "hidden agenda". It seems to attract a lot of fanatics pushing their world views.

Comment: You should have supplied the quote from Dictionary.com, which gives definitions of four senses. Obviously, in school the Dictionary.com definition (4) was being used, while you for some reason have stopped at (1). Words are often unbiddable in this way (having conflicting definitions).

Comment: I just used that as my example one I had read them all but it just didn't make any sense for my brain to handle.  Although in fact I did read them all.

Comment: The terms "humanism" and "secular humanism" have been tossed about for maybe 50 years now, between philosophers, religious theorists, and various fanatics on both sides of the religion/atheism divide.  They are often used in a pejorative sense by religious zealots, while, on the other side, some folks choose to use them to describe their own philosophies.  As a result, the terms are not particularly precise or informative, except in limited contexts.

Comment: I would like that in the answer section it is a really good answer so thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm too lazy to dig up the required references.

Comment: That is fine...I would do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I find these kinds of questions get a pretty good answer [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism):

> Humanism is a philosophical and ethical stance that emphasizes the value and agency of human beings, individually and collectively, and affirms their ability to improve their lives through the use of reason and ingenuity as opposed to submitting blindly to tradition and authority or sinking into cruelty and brutality.[1] The term was coined in 1808 by the early nineteenth century German educational reformer and theologian Friedrich Niethammer and gradually adopted into English. Niethammer had wished to introduce into German education the humane values of ancient Greece and Rome. Niethhammer was a Lutheran theologian. Since the twentieth century, however, Anglophone humanist movements have usually been aligned with secularism, and today humanism typically refers to a non-theistic life stance centred on human agency and looking to science rather than revelation from a supernatural source to understand the world.[2][3]

Humanism, like many other -isms, is an ideology (or perhaps, set of ideologies) that has shifted and morphed over the years, variously including and excluding ideas (such as secularism or non-theism) depending on which proponent of the ideology is speaking.

In addition, proponents and opponents of the ideology tend to emphasize different aspects. For example, a proponent might emphasize "the value and agency of human beings" while either a proponent or an opponent might emphasize that it is "non-theistic" if that would be attractive to the audience. But both are correct in that most forms of the ideology purport to provide a way forward emphasizing the former, while assuming (or in some cases, arguing) the latter.

Comment: I was told Wikipedia isn't always correct.

Comment: True, but it's usually a good place to start. Get your bearings using Wikipedia, then corroborate and dig deeper using other sources.

Comment: Okay that is a good idea I will try that out.  Thank you.

Comment: A satisfactory Wikipedia article will always have several high-quality references. Unfortunately, many of the five million articles were written before the arrangements for checking them were as tight as they are today, and lack good references.